# Blocking Applications via LDAP

Tags: ubuntu, ldap

I have already setup an openLDAP server(Ubuntu server) and a LDAP client(Ubuntu). From my experience with Active Directory, `Software Restriction Policy` can be applied onto a `Group Policy Object` which is then applied onto a user, group, organizational unit, etc to allow or disable access to applications. Is there a similar method to block applications from unauthorized users for Linux?

Comment: Which LDAP server are you using? Or are you looking for a generic answer?

Comment: I am using openLDAP.

Comment: Have you looked at the OpenLDAP access control documentation? (http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html) I am sure that the model is different and you will have some mapping to do, but I would be surprised if could not accomplish something similar. Others may have a more specific answer.